# merging multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have 3 numpy arrays which store image data of shape (4,100,100).

```
arr1= np.load(r'C:\Users\x\Desktop\py\output\a1.npy')
arr2= np.load(r'C:\Users\x\Desktop\py\output\a2.npy')
arr3= np.load(r'C:\Users\x\Desktop\py\output\a3.npy')
```

I want to merge all 3 arrays into 1 array.
I have tried in this way:

```
merg_arr = np.zeros((len(arr1)+len(arr2)+len(arr3), 4,100,100), dtype=input_img.dtype)
```

now this make an array of the required length but I don't know how to copy all the data in this array. may be using a loop?

Comment: What you man by merge into one array? do you want to concatenate them? do you want to sum up the pixel values? What would be the final shape of your array?

Comment: Oh.. i missed the `(len(arr1)+len(arr2)+len(arr3), 4, ...` part. Can you explaian why you want a shape of [12, 4, 100, 100]? Either [3, 4, 100, 100] or [12, 100, 100] would seem to make more sense.

Comment: i have 3 arrays of shape (60, 4,100,100), (14, 4,100,100), (6, 4,100,100).. I want them in a single array of shape  (80,4,100,100)

Comment: I'm taking off the duplicate flag.  That SO question dealt with 1d arrays, which need `vstack`.  Here the arrays have the right shape to concatenate on the 1st dimension.  It's evident from the comments that the problem isn't with concatenate.  Something else is going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
merge_arr = np.concatenate([arr1, arr2, arr3], axis=0)
```

[`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) arranges arrays along a new dimension. Their dimensions (except for the first) need to match.

Demo:

```
arr1 = np.empty((60, 4, 10, 10))
arr2 = np.empty((14, 4, 10, 10))
arr3 = np.empty((6, 4, 10, 10))
merge_arr = np.concatenate([arr1, arr2, arr3], axis=0)
print(merge_arr.shape)  # (80, 4, 10, 10)
```

Comment: all of them are of different size, like (60,4,100,100), (14,4,100,100),(6,4,100,100)

Comment: @FahadJahangir you did not say so in the question ;)

Comment: so here is the problem! the resultant array has all zeros in it. like this: 
[[[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
   ...,

Comment: @FahadJahangir time to check if your input arrays have all zeros. Or maybe there are zeros on the borders only. Try `np.unique(merge_arr)` to see if there are really only zeros in an array.

Comment: well the input arrays don't have zeros.. they have data like 
[[[[215 185 118 ...,  60  25  18]
   [228 185  90 ...,  42  18  25]
   [219 172 100 ...,  18  18  81]
   ..., 
   [240 172 100 ..., 118 118 134]
   [209 100  70 ...,  81  81 118]
   [126  25  60 ...,  60  51  90]]

Comment: @FahadJahangir there must be a mistake somewhere in your code.. can't clarify that in comments, though. Best create a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with toy data and if you can reproduce the problem ask an new specific question.