# Using a ''for loop'' to copy numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
array1 = np.load(r'C:\Users\x\array1.npy')
array2 = np.load(r'C:\Users\x\array2.npy')
```

I have to merge them in single array, so what I did was:

```
merg_arr = np.zeros((len(array1)+len(array2), 4, 100, 100), dtype=input_img.dtype)

for i in range(len(array1)+len(array2)):
    if i < len(array1):
        merg_arr[i] = array1[i]
    else:
        merge_arr[i] = array2[i-len(array1)]
```

It works in that way in case of 2 input arrays. Now I have 5 input arrays instead of two. But I am confused how to use the for loop in this case?

The shape of the 5 arrays and the expected output are:

```
array1: (7, 4 ,100, 100) 
array2: (14, 4 ,100, 100) 
array3: (5, 4 ,100, 100) 
array4: (8, 4 ,100, 100) 
array5: (66, 4 ,100, 100)
merg_arr: (100,4,100,100)
```

Comment: See how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This a retry of http://stackoverflow.com/a/43847783

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) them along the first axis:

```
merg_arr = np.concatenate([array1, array2, array3, array4, array5], axis=0)
```

You can also do it with the `for`-loop:

```
arrays = (array1, array2, array3, array4, array5)
length_sum = sum(len(arr) for arr in arrays)
merge_arr = np.zeros((length_sum, 4,100,100), dtype=arrays[0].dtype)
start = 0
for arr in arrays:
    end = start + len(arr)
    merge_arr[start:end] = arr
    start = end
```

However `concatenate` is probably much easier.